# List col1 and col2 having every col1 value with multiple col2 values

Tags: sql-server, select

Goal is to list col1 and col2 having every col1 value with multiple col2 values. Duplicates on col1 co2 combination will have to be removed.

I am doing this to get the result table. 
With this query the first column col1 can be displayed.
Is it the right approach? Or is there a simpler way?

```
with t1 as 
(
select distinct [col1], col2, count([col1]) as col1Count 
from [Table1] 
where [col1] <> null 
or len(ltrim(rtrim([col1]))) > 0 
group by [col1], col2 
having count([col1]) > 1 
)
select [col1] from t1 group by t1.[col1] having count([col1]) > 1
```

**Source Table**

```
col1   col2   col3
====================
a     a1     blah
a     a1     blah2
a    aa1    blah
a    aa1    blah3
a1    b1    blah
b    b1    blah
b    b1    blah2
b    bb1    blah
b    bb1    blah2
b1    c1    blah
c    c1    blah
c    c1    blah2
c    cc1    blah
c    cc1    blah3
c1    d1    blah
```

**Result table**

```
col1    col2
===========
a    a1
a    aa1
b    b1
b    bb1
c    c1
c    cc1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by col1, col2` and a condition in the `having` clause:

```
select col1, col2
from tablename
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1
```

If there are `null`s or blank values in `col1` then you can add a `where` clause:

```
where (col1 is not null) and (len(rtrim(ltrim(col1))) > 0)
```

or

```
where len(rtrim(ltrim(coalesce(col1, '')))) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=729db4dc092721a332a10b871503ef41).
Results:

```
col1    col2
------------
a       a1
a       aa1
b       b1
b       bb1
c       c1
c       cc1
```